# WinForms Draw parts of image at a rotated rectangle frame

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on image transitions for my digital photo frame and am trying to achieve this transition:

[image: Illustrated example]

It's more of a radar-style transition with the wiping effect going from one side to another in a 180 degree angle. Although, it doesn't appear that "blocky", I just spaced out the rectangles for illustration purposes. The entire thing should be a smooth transitions without any FPS stuttering effects.

My logic is to draw the specific part of the image at (theta) rotation angle like my drawing above - but that will end up drawing 100's of rectangles that sweeps across the screen.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? If not, could I have a few code tips to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is practically impossible to have without any FPS shuttering especially in bigger screens because WinForms uses CPU only rendering. You will have to embed OpenTK (if you want to use OpenGL) or Direct3D frame inside, or maybe WPF where you do the animation.

If you use any of them (for example OpenGL), you have to load it as a texture, and the animation would be done on the triangle level (dragging the corners only) not on the image itself.

If you want to have a curved surface, like a real page transition, I recommend to use a bezier patch as is found here: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bezier_patches__fullscreen_fix/18003/

This coding takes a lot of time, and is much more over the purpose of StackOverflow (to setup a full OpenGL/DirectX control + how to do a Bezier patch if you want to set it up).

If you don't want to embed anything, you may look to this transformations tutorial using WPF, but I'm not 100% sure that this is what you need:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14895/WPF-Tutorial-Part-Transformations

Comment: I've tried animations in WPF; while I was successful at "emulating" the effect, a lot the mathematical calculations was hard coded with +- 10 if-else statements because I used the LinearGradientBrush & DoubleAnimation to simulate the wiping effect. Is there a way to set the LinearGradientBrush point of rotation at 1 side like my diagram or should I just use the hard-coded version for now? It works smoothly without FPS stutters because I did that in WPF, which uses GPU and hardware acceleration, but just not efficiently.

Comment: If you rely on WinForms, I recommend you embed OpenTK. OpenTK has an OpenGL control, so you don't have to use any "weird" stuff, and it also has a sample OpenGL texture example, where it loads an Bitmap (which can be created for example redirecting your drawing to a Bitmap).

This will not make you rely on WPF, and you can keep this coding for your future Xamarin/iOS/Android sample.

Comment: I'm a lucky 4K laptop owner, and I can say that if your application runs full-screen, I honestly don't know how can you move some 8 millions pixels on CPU with let's say 25 ms hard limit to have smooth animation. Even you would move just 1/2 of them, still imagine 4 million pixels to process. The single way I would know is to you to rewrite with OpenCL which would be impossibly hard.